# Errors in solving problems with Gekko python

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve the problem as follows with Gekko in python.

[image]

(1) However, I got some errors **APM model error: string > 15000  characters
Consider breaking up the line into multiple equations The may also be due to only using newline character CR
instead of CR LF (for Windows) or LF (for MacOS/Linux)
To fix this problem, save APM file with appropriate newline characters
STOPPING...**

Is it possible to solve this problem when I increases N to larger number such as 500 or 600?

(2) I have another question about m.min3 function. If I define a variable v like v=m.Var(value=3) and implement m.min3(v, -50), why the result is 0, not -50?

```
# Import package
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# Define parameters
P_CO = 600.0                    # $/tonCO
beta_CO2 = 1.0                  # no unit
P_CO2 = 39.0                    # $/tonCO2eq
E_ref = 3.1022616               # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_dir = -1.600570692            # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_indir_others = 0.3339226804   # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_indir_elec_cons = 18.46607256 # GJ/tonCO
C1_CAPEX = 285695.0             # no unit
C2_CAPEX = 188.42               # no unit
C1_FOX = 82282.0                # no unit
C2_FOX = 24.094                 # no unit
C1_ROX = 4471.5                 # no unit
C2_ROX = 96.034                 # no unit
C1_UOX = 1983.7                 # no unit
C2_UOX = 249.79                 # no unit
r = 0.08                        # discount rate
N = 100                         # number of scenarios
T = 30                          # total time period
GWP_init = 0.338723235          # 2020 Electricity GWP in EU 27 countries
theta_max = 1600000             # Max capacity

# Function to make GWP_EU matrix (TxN matrix)
def Electricity_GWP(GWP_init, n_years, num_episodes):

    GWP_mean = 0.36258224*np.exp(-0.16395611*np.arange(1, n_years+2)) + 0.03091272
    GWP_mean = GWP_mean.reshape(-1,1)
    GWP_Yearly = np.tile(GWP_mean, num_episodes) 

    noise = np.zeros((n_years+1, num_episodes))
    stdev2050 = GWP_mean[-1] * 0.25 
    stdev = np.arange(0, stdev2050 * (1 + 1/n_years), stdev2050/n_years)

    for i in range(n_years+1):
        noise[i,:] = np.random.normal(0, stdev[i], num_episodes) 

    GWP_forecast = GWP_Yearly + noise 

    return GWP_forecast

GWP_EU = Electricity_GWP(GWP_init, T, N) # (T+1)*N matrix
GWP_EU = GWP_EU[1:,:] # T*N matrix

print(np.shape(GWP_EU))

# Build Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
theta = m.Array(m.Var, (N,1), lb=0, ub=theta_max)
demand = np.ones((T,1))
demand[0] = 8031887.589
for k in range(1,11):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.026 
for k in range(11,21):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.016
for k in range(21,T):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.011 
demand = 0.12 * demand
demand = np.tile(demand, N) # T*N matrix

print(np.shape(demand))

obj=0
obj = sum(((1/(1+r))**(t+1))*((P_CO*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) \
        + beta_CO2*P_CO2*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])*(E_ref-E_dir- 
E_indir_others-E_indir_elec_cons*GWP_EU[t,s]) \
        - (C1_CAPEX + C2_CAPEX*theta[s]) - (C1_FOX + C2_FOX*theta[s]) - (C1_ROX + C2_ROX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) - (C1_UOX + C2_UOX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])))
for s in range(N) for t in range(T))/N
            
m.Maximize(obj)
m.solve()    

print(theta)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `m.sum()` as below and it worked but I got negative DOF (Degrees of Freedom).

```py
obj = m.sum([m.sum([((1/(1+r))**(t+1))*((P_CO*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) \
     + beta_CO2*P_CO2*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s]) \
      *(E_ref-E_dir-E_indir_others-E_indir_elec_cons*GWP_EU[t,s]) \
     - (C1_CAPEX + C2_CAPEX*theta[s]) \
     - (C1_FOX + C2_FOX*theta[s]) \
     - (C1_ROX + C2_ROX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) \
     - (C1_UOX + C2_UOX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s]))) \
          for t in range(T)]) for s in range(N)])
m.Maximize(obj)
m.solve()
```

In detail, the warning message is,

```
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  101
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  51201
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  3201
   Equations    :  39001
   Residuals    :  39001
 
 Number of state variables:    51201
 Number of total equations: -  39101
 Number of slack variables: -  24000
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -11900
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
```

There is a Warning of negative DOF. I've posted an additional question about this issue: [Negative degrees of fredom when using GEKKO python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162557/negative-degrees-of-fredom-when-using-gekko-python)

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution and for the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162557/negative-degrees-of-fredom-when-using-gekko-python A follow-up question is most appropriate for any additional issues.