# Negative degrees of fredom when using GEKKO python

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gekko

[image]

I'm trying to solve the optimization problem as above.
And my code is as belows.

It worked, but I got the **negative degrees of freedom** problem.

And the objective value was also negative, which I did not expect to be. I expected the positive one.

I can't understand why this happened and don't know how this problem can be solved.

Can somebody give me a suggestion?

**Code**

```
# Import package
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# Define parameters
P_CO = 600                      # $/tonCO
beta_CO2 = 1                    # no unit
P_CO2 = 60                      # $/tonCO2eq
E_ref = 3.1022616               # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_dir = -1.600570692            # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_indir_others = 0.3339226804   # tonCO2eq/tonCO
E_indir_elec_cons = 18.46607256 # GJ/tonCO
C1_CAPEX = 285695               # no unit
C2_CAPEX = 188.42               # no unit
C1_FOX = 82282                  # no unit
C2_FOX = 24.094                 # no unit
C1_ROX = 4471.5                 # no unit
C2_ROX = 96.034                 # no unit
C1_UOX = 1983.7                 # no unit
C2_UOX = 249.79                 # no unit
r = 0.08                        # discount rate
N = 10                          # number of scenarios
T = 30                          # total time period
GWP_init = 0.338723235          # 2020 Electricity GWP in EU 27 countries
theta_max = 1600000             # Max capacity

# Function to make GWP_EU matrix (TxN matrix)
def Electricity_GWP(GWP_init, n_years, num_episodes):

    GWP_mean = 0.36258224*np.exp(-0.16395611*np.arange(1, n_years+2)) + 0.03091272
    GWP_mean = GWP_mean.reshape(-1,1)
    GWP_Yearly = np.tile(GWP_mean, num_episodes) 

    noise = np.zeros((n_years+1, num_episodes))
    stdev2050 = GWP_mean[-1] * 0.25 
    stdev = np.arange(0, stdev2050 * (1 + 1/n_years), stdev2050/n_years)

    for i in range(n_years+1):
        noise[i,:] = np.random.normal(0, stdev[i], num_episodes) 

    GWP_forecast = GWP_Yearly + noise 

    return GWP_forecast

GWP_EU = Electricity_GWP(GWP_init, T, N) # (T+1)*N matrix
GWP_EU = GWP_EU[1:,:] # T*N matrix

print(np.shape(GWP_EU))

# Build Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
theta = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0, ub=theta_max)
demand = np.ones((T,1))
demand[0] = 8031887.589
for k in range(1,11):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.026 
for k in range(11,21):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.016
for k in range(21,T):
    demand[k] = demand[k-1] * 1.011 
demand = 0.12 * demand
demand = np.tile(demand, N) # T*N matrix

print(np.shape(demand))

obj = m.sum([m.sum([((1/(1+r))**(t+1))*((P_CO*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])) \
            + (beta_CO2*P_CO2*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])*(E_ref-E_dir-E_indir_others-E_indir_elec_cons*GWP_EU[t,s])) \
            - (C1_CAPEX+C2_CAPEX*theta[s]+C1_FOX+C2_FOX*theta[s])-(C1_ROX+C2_ROX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s])+C1_UOX+C2_UOX*m.min3(demand[t,s], theta[s]))) for t in range(T)]) for s in range(N)])
m.Maximize(obj/N)
m.solve()
```

**Output message**

```
(30, 10)
(30, 10)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  11
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  5121
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  321
   Equations    :  3901
   Residuals    :  3901
 
 Number of state variables:    5121
 Number of total equations: -  3911
 Number of slack variables: -  2400
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -1190
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:     18.61 NLPi:    5 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj: -1.87E+09 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  18.619200000000003 sec
 Objective      :  -1.8677021320161405E+9
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative DOF warning is because of the slack variables that are created when using the `min3()` function. It is only a warning that if all of the inequalities are active then this could lead to an over-specified system of equations (more equations than variables). If there is a successful solution then this warning can be ignored.

The negative objective is because most solvers require a minimization of the objective. Gekko automatically converts `m.Maximize(obj)` to `m.Minimize(-obj)`. This is an equivalent objective. If you'd like to report the maximization and the positive objective, use the following at the end:

```py
print('Objective: ',-m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

Comment: I understand it! Thank you for giving me an answer. By the way, as I increase N to large number (500), I got another error again as follows.

    Memory allocation failed

    Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details.


Is my code not available for large N?

Comment: The Windows version of the local executable is 32-bit so it runs out of memory when the problem is over 4 GB in size. The MacOS, Linux, or cloud service all use 64-bit executables so they shouldn’t run out of memory.

Comment: There are also some things you can do to reduce the memory such as pre-solve with m.options.REDUCE=3

Comment: Oh I see. I tried m.options.REDUCE=3 for N=300 with remote=False, but the error which was out of memory still existed. So, I tried N=300 with remote=True instead, but it was not done even after 10 hours. I still don't know how long it will take :( Is there another method to use large N with remote=False?

Comment: I have a few suggestions. Could you create another question so that I can give a more detailed response than is allowed in these comments?

Comment: Yes, I'll make an another question!